# How to 301 redirect all pages from one domain to one single page on a different domain

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I´m trying to do a 301 redirect in a htacess file. I want to point **all pages** on one domain to **one single page** on another domain and I do not want to manually redirect all single pages.

Ex: www.olddomain.com/1.html and www.olddomain.com/2.html should both point to www.newdomain.com.

Hope anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com/one-single-page.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn´t seem to have any effect at all.

Comment: Do you have a RewriteLog? Therein you should find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but this works fine for me to accomplish what you want, i actually need to opposite, for each page from old domain to redirect to new domain but keep inner structure so ill keep looking i guess!

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/ http://www.newdomain.com
```