# .htaccess redirect all pages except a few pages redirecting with specific page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

After searching for many post here, I found no luck they are slightly different but I can't handle for now. Please pardon me about this. This are post here I've tried:

- [How to Redirect All urls to a new domain in apache, except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629430/how-to-redirect-all-urls-to-a-new-domain-in-apache-except-one)
- [.htaccess rule redirect all pages except a few provided ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864366/htaccess-rule-redirect-all-pages-except-a-few-provided-ones)
- [How to 301 redirect all pages from one domain to one single page on a different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959477/how-to-301-redirect-all-pages-from-one-domain-to-one-single-page-on-a-different)

Here is what I want to acquired:

- all url in www.olddomain.com permanint redirect to www.exampledomain.com/page,
- and in www.olddomain.com have a page that should be redirect to www.exampledomain.com/pagesample

*Please note*: the old olddomain.com have no files except the index and this htaccess, and the www.exampledomain.com is a wordpress site.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused about this sentence:

> www.olddomain.com is have a page will be redirect

I'm assuming you mean www.olddomain.com/page redirect to www.exampledomain.com/pagesample

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*olddomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /page/
RewriteRule ^ http://www.exampledomain.com/pagesample [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.exampledomain.com/page/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. It helps much but the second condition (`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*olddomain\.com$ RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.exampledomain.com/page/$1 [L,R=301]` ) didn't work. But when I remove the **slash (/)** in `RewriteRule ^/(.*) http:` -> `RewriteRule ^(.*) http:` seems work fine.